# Cant add 1 to Exponential number in python

Tags: python, numbers, exponential

I have a number in exponential format and want to add 1 to the number. Why is python printing the original number?

```
num = 1.1920928955078124e+16
print(num)     # == 1.1920928955078124e+16
print(num + 1) # == 1.1920928955078124e+16
print(num + 2) # == 1.1920928955078126e+16
```

However when I add 2, it works and returns original number + 2

Thanks for help

Comment: Do the answers to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken) help at all?

Answer (score 1):

Your number is represented by a float

```
type(1.1920928955078124e+16)  # <class 'float'>
```

You can cast it to int using `int(num)`.

Floating point numbers also have limited precision.
If you need more precision, you can use `decimal.Decimal`

```
from decimal import Decimal
Decimal('1.1920928955078124e+16') + 1  # Decimal('11920928955078125')
```

Or a library like `numpy`

```
import numpy as np
np.int64(1.1920928955078124e+16) + 1  # 11920928955078125
```

Answer (score 1):

scientific notation is always represented as a float.
try:

```
num = 1.1920928955078124e+16 #float

print(int(num))  #Convert that float to int
# 11920928955078124
print(int(num) + 1)
# 11920928955078125
```